# Static table generation works with GCC but not clang; is clang bugged?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, static-members, partial-specialization

I wrote some code once upon a time that generated a static table/array at compile time for some template metaprogramming (the idea is that C-style strings can be built at compile time (they're just `char` arrays)). The idea and the code is based off [David Lin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/63757/david-lin)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3499919/1287251):

```
#include <iostream>

const int ARRAY_SIZE = 5;

template <int N, int I=N-1>
class Table : public Table<N, I-1>
{
public:
    static const int dummy;
};

template <int N>
class Table<N, 0>
{
public:
    static const int dummy;
    static int array[N];
};

template <int N, int I>
const int Table<N, I>::dummy = Table<N, 0>::array[I] = I*I + 0*Table<N, I-1>::dummy;

template <int N>
int Table<N, 0>::array[N];

template class Table<ARRAY_SIZE>;

int main(int, char**)
{
    const int *compilerFilledArray = Table<ARRAY_SIZE>::array;
    for (int i=0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i)
        std::cout<<compilerFilledArray[i]<<std::endl;
}
```

Compiling this code with GCC 4.9.2 works:

```
$ g++-4.9 -Wall -pedantic b.cpp
$ ./a.out
0
1
4
9
16
```

Clang 3.5 complains, though:

```
$ clang++ -Wall -pedantic b.cpp
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Table<5, 0>::dummy", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in b-b8a447.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

`dummy` and `array` are both given definitions outside of the `Table` class (where they're declared). As far as I can tell, this should satisfy the linker requirements.

Is this a bug with clang?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every primary and partial specializations static data members must be defined separately.

```
template <int N, int I>
const int Table<N, I>::dummy = …;
```

The only thing defined here is `Table<N, I>::dummy` - the primary specializations static data member. [temp.class.spec.mfunc]/1<sup>1</sup>:

> Class template partial specialization members that are used in a way
>   that requires a definition shall be defined; **the definitions of
>   members of the primary template are never used as definitions for
>   members of a class template partial specialization.**

This also implies that GCC is wrong here. That's a bug.
Eitherway, adding

```
template <int N>
const int Table<N, 0>::dummy = 0;
```

Should compile fine.

---

<sup>1)</sup>
In particular, in the same section as the quote above:

> The template parameter list of a member of a class template partial
>   specialization shall match the template parameter list of the class
>   template partial specialization.
>   The template argument list of a
>   member of a class template partial specialization shall match the
>   template argument list of the class template partial specialization.

That means that the argument lists used for defining the partial specialization and its member **must be the same**. Otherwise that member is never defined.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! It's a shame I can only vote once. Also, I'm looking forward to the standard quotes when you get them.

Comment: @Cornstalks They're there :)

Comment: Can you add a link to the gcc bug report please?